# Returning array from ctypes doesn't work with Numpy >1.14

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I am trying to return an array containing 2 floats from a C++ program using Ctypes.

My C++ code looks like this:

```cpp
    extern "C" float* simulationSet(int cd, int ci, float cdi, int ad, int ai, float adi, int numReps){
      static float retArray[2];
        
      //DO SOME STUFF
        
      retArray[0]=x;
        retArray[1]=y;
        cout<<"0="<<retArray[0]<<"\n";
        cout<<"1="<<retArray[1]<<"\n";
        return retArray;
    }
```

and the Python I am using is:

```
    import numpy as np
    import sys
    import ctypes
    from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer

    _ACC = ctypes.CDLL('ACC.so')
    _ACC.simulationSet.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_float,ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_int,ctypes.c_float,ctypes.c_int)
    _ACC.simulationSet.restype = ndpointer(dtype=ctypes.c_float, shape=(2,))
    #_ACC.simulationSet.restype =ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float*2)

    ad=1
    ai=3
    adi=1.0
    cd=1
    ci=3
    cdi=1.0
    numReps=2

    results=_ACC.simulationSet(cd,ci,cdi,ad,ai,adi,numReps)

    print(results)
```

But, when I try to run it, I get the error:

```
    1 3 1 1 3 1 2
    0=0
    1=1
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "tester.py", line 29, in <module>
        results=_ACC.simulationSet(cd,ci,cdi,ad,ai,adi,numReps)
      File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 948, in GetResult
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/ctypeslib.py", line 211, in _check_retval_
        return self.contents
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/ctypeslib.py", line 222, in contents
        buffer = ctypes.cast(self, ctypes.POINTER(full_ctype)).contents
    ValueError: NULL pointer access
```

and I compile with:

```
    g++ -shared -o ACC.so CPP/*.cpp -std=c++11 -O3 -fPIC
```

edit:  I tried it on a different machine and got this error:

```html
  File "tester.py", line 29, in <module>
    results=_ACC.simulationSet(cd,ci,cdi,ad,ai,adi,numReps)
  File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 911, in GetResult
  File "/home/chase/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/ctypeslib.py", line 183, in _check_retval_
    return array(self)
ValueError: '<P' is not a valid PEP 3118 buffer format string
```

edit2: On the machine with the Null pointer error, its Python 3.8.5 and Numpy 1.19.0

On the version with the Pep 3118 error, its Python 3.7.0 and Numpy 1.15.0

Comment: Can't reproduce. It works fine when I try it.

Comment: I tried on a different machine and got this error:  File "tester.py", line 29, in <module>
    results=_ACC.simulationSet(cd,ci,cdi,ad,ai,adi,numReps)
  File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 911, in GetResult
  File "/home/chase/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/ctypeslib.py", line 183, in _check_retval_
    return array(self)
ValueError: '<P' is not a valid PEP 3118 buffer format string

Comment: What exact versions of Python and NumPy are you on?

Comment: On the machine with the Null pointer error, its Python 3.8.5 and Numpy 1.19.0

On the version with the Pep 3118 error, its Python 3.7.0 and Numpy 1.15.0

Comment: I still can't reproduce "ValueError: NULL pointer access". I tried Python 3.8.5 and NumPy 1.19.0, and it worked fine for me with those exact versions. As for the error "ValueError: '<P' is not a valid PEP 3118 buffer format string", it's a bug in NumPy 1.15.x, which you can avoid by either downgrading to 1.14.6 or older, or upgrading to 1.16.0 or newer.

Comment: Thank you, I upgraded numpy on the Pep3118 machine and everything is working now.